# C - STM32f4 error on function call when initializing GPIO

Tags: c, compiler-errors, embedded, stm32f4discovery

I have written a program to initialize GPIO for STM32F4 but for some reason after I try to build this code:

Include ST's header:

```
#include "stm32f4_discovery.h"
```

Defining starting adresses of GPIO:

```
#define GPIOA ((struct GPIO *) 0x40020000)
#define GPIOB ((struct GPIO *) 0x40020400)
#define GPIOC ((struct GPIO *) 0x40020800)
#define GPIOD ((struct GPIO *) 0x40020C00)
#define GPIOE ((struct GPIO *) 0x40021000)
#define GPIOF ((struct GPIO *) 0x40021400)
#define GPIOG ((struct GPIO *) 0x40021800)
#define GPIOH ((struct GPIO *) 0x40021C00)
#define GPIOI ((struct GPIO *) 0x40022000)
```

Reset and Clock Control:

```
#define RCC   ((uint32_t *) 0x40023830)

#define IN              uint8_t 0
#define OUT             uint8_t 1
#define NO_PULL         uint8_t 0
#define PULL_UP         uint8_t 1
#define PULL_DOWN       uint8_t 2
#define PUSH_PULL       uint8_t 0
#define OPEN_DRAIN      uint8_t 1
#define S2MHz           uint8_t 0
#define S25MHz          uint8_t 1
#define S50MHz          uint8_t 2
#define S100MHz         uint8_t 3
```

Basic GPIO struct:

```
struct GPIO {
    uint32_t MODER;
    uint32_t TYPER;
    uint32_t OSPEEDR;
    uint32_t PUPDR;
    uint32_t IDR;
    uint32_t ODR;
    uint16_t BSSR_SET;
    uint16_t BSSR_RESET;
};

void Init_GPIO(struct GPIO *GPIO_Type, uint32_t GPIO_Mode, uint8_t in_out, uint8_t pull, uint8_t push_pull, uint8_t freq) {
    // Set MODER:

    if (in_out) {
        GPIO_Type->MODER |= (1 << GPIO_Mode);
        GPIO_Type->MODER &= ~(2 << GPIO_Mode);
    }
    else {
        GPIO_Type->MODER &= ~(3 << GPIO_Mode);
    }

    // Set PUPDR:

    if (!pull) {
        GPIO_Type->PUPDR &= ~(3 << GPIO_Mode);
    }
    else if (pull == 1) {
        GPIO_Type->PUPDR |= (1 << GPIO_Mode);
        GPIO_Type->PUPDR &= ~(2 << GPIO_Mode);
    }
    else if (pull == 2) {
        GPIO_Type->PUPDR |= (2 << GPIO_Mode);
        GPIO_Type->PUPDR &= ~(1 << GPIO_Mode);
    }

    // Set TYPER:

    if (push_pull) {
        GPIO_Type->TYPER &= ~(1 << GPIO_Mode);
    }
    else {
        GPIO_Type->TYPER |= (1 << GPIO_Mode);
    }

    // Set OSPEEDR:

    if (!freq) {
        GPIO_Type->OSPEEDR &= ~(3 << GPIO_Mode);
    }
    else if (freq == 1) {
        GPIO_Type->OSPEEDR |= (1 << GPIO_Mode);
        GPIO_Type->OSPEEDR &= (2 << GPIO_Mode);
    }
    else if (freq == 2) {
        GPIO_Type->OSPEEDR |= (2 << GPIO_Mode);
        GPIO_Type->OSPEEDR &= ~(1 << GPIO_Mode);
    }
    else {
        GPIO_Type->OSPEEDR &= (3 << GPIO_Mode);
    }
}

/**
  * @brief  Main program
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
    Init_GPIO(GPIOD,  12, OUT, NO_PULL, PUSH_PULL, S2MHz);
    Init_GPIO(GPIOA, 0, IN, NO_PULL, PUSH_PULL, S2MHz);

    while (1) {

    }
}
```

I get the following errors which refer to `Init_GPIO` fucntion call:

```
Error[Pe254]: type name is not allowed C:\Users\..\main.c 93 
Error[Pe165]: too few arguments in function call C:\Users\..\main.c 93
Error[Pe018]: expected a ")" C:\Users\..\main.c 93 
Error[Pe254]: type name is not allowed C:\Users\..\main.c 94
Error[Pe165]: too few arguments in function call C:\Users\..\main.c 94
Error[Pe018]: expected a ")" C:\Users\..\main.c 94
Error while running C/C++ Compiler
```

Comment: Instead of breaking up your function, post it exactly as it is, verbatim, plain copy-paste. And if you need to add comments, then add those as actual comments in the code. Also show *where* in the code you have the errors, again with comments in the actual code.

Comment: By the way, if you look at the preprocessed code (stop the compiler after preprocessing) then you should get a hint about what's wrong. Here's another hint: Take a closer look at those `IN`, `OUT` etc. macros.

Comment: When you get weird compiler errors like this, they are often caused by missing braces or semicolons. Look at the first error in the list, then look at the code immediately before that line. Including the code in any header files that were included before it. It can also be helpful to compile parts of your code with a different compiler, to get better error messages.

Comment: The board header stm32f4_discovery.h includes the device header "stm32f4xx.h" whch defined RCC, GPIOA, GPIOB etc.  Why are you redefining them?

Comment: The compiler helpfully indicates where the error is at lines 93/94 but you have abstracted your code so that it is no longer easy to determine which line it refers to.

Comment: Further if you define `USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER` and add the necessary standard peripheral library components, equivalents to `Init_GPIO()` and definitions equivalent to `NO_PULL` are correctly defined for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macros `IN`, `OUT` etc. are incorrectly defined and when expanded in the calls to `Init_GPIO()` make no syntactic sense.

Change:

```
#define IN              uint8_t 0
```

to

```
#define IN              ((uint8_t)0)
```

for example, and similarly for the other similarly define macros.

Whenever you get a compiler error on a line containing pre=processor macros you have to consider what that line looks like after macro expansion, because that is what the compiler is "seeing".

Alternatively, use the ST Standard Peripheral Library where GPIO initialisation and similar symbols, types and macros to those you have defined are already *correctly* defined.  An example of using the standard peripheral library to access GPIO can be found [here](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/04/stm32f429-discovery-gpio-tutorial-with-onboard-leds-and-button/).  The author refers to it as the CMSIS Library, but strictly it is merely *CMSIS compliant* but STM32 specific.  Other examples are included with the library itself.  The library is likely included with you toolchain (which appears to be IAR), but can be downloaded from ST [here](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-libraries/stsw-stm32065.html) - you can probably ignore stuff about the library being superseded by STM32Cube unless you want that kind of hand-holding an code bloat and are not likley to ever want to port your code to non STM32 platforms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer you just saved me a lot of time.